# Object disappear when zooming in NOT in camera view

Tags: objects, 3d-view

I don't know the reason why but while I was zooming in on my object it has suddenly decided to disappear and now if a zoom even just a little bit I can't see it anymore, both in object and edit mode. It appears only in camera view. I set the start clipping value to 0, but it doesn't seem to work and I don't know what the problem could be.

Can anyone help me?

[image: set ups]

Comment: Can you add screenshot of viewport, that describes your problem?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the camera to the mesh - the "," key on the numpad